# Move local changes to new branch and reset current branch

Tags: git

I started working on my master branch and forgot I needed to fix something. On this master branch I currently have uncommitted local changes which I want to move to a new branch. Next to this, I want to have a clean master branch where I can start new work.
[image]

I tried to stash the changes of the master branch with `git stash` then created a new branch with `git checkout -b new-branch`. After I used `git stash pop` to leave the local changes of master branch on the newly created branch. To reset my master branch I went back to master with `git checkout master` and did a hard reset `git reset --hard`. This resulted in a clean master branch, but also left the new branch empty..

How can I achieve that the changes on the new branch are not getting reset?

Comment: Did you make any commits on master you also want moved?

Comment: Good one,I do not have any commits which I want moved. Just the local changes

Comment: Then can't you simply do `git checkout -b NEW_BRANCH_NAME` ?

Comment: The local changes will be on the new branch indeed. IfI use `git reset --hard` on master, it will remove local changes on master, but also on the new branch?

Comment: Why do you need to reset at all? Are you perhaps confused about the distinction between working folder and branch?

Comment: I’ve been working on feature-B on master, while fix-A was a high priority. Therefore I want to move feature-B to a new branch and start working on fix-A on master and push it to a remote repo. This means I need a clean mast branch (no local changes from feature-B) to start working on fix-A. After this I’m able to continue working on feature-B

Comment: First, unless you start adding work trees, you only have 1 working folder, so you can only have uncommitted changes *once*, not per branch. This means that you need to "get rid of" the uncommitted changes intended for feature-B while you work on your fix on master, without losing said changes. There are two ways. 1) checkout a new branch (like I showed above), then commit your changes on that branch (you can ammend them later if they're not done) and then check out master again or 2) stash your changes. Either way **you should not be using reset!**

Comment: Your current uncommited changes are not on any branch, they're in the working folder that is *based* on the master branch. You can, however, attempt to check out your other branch. If git is able to do so, because your uncommitted changes are not in conflict with the differences between master and your other branch, then the working folder will now be based on that other branch, and then have your uncommitted changes as before. If you then make a commit, that will be on this other branch, not master. Master will then be untouched.

Comment: If you're not able to check out the other branch, then there is a conflict, and you will then have to stash your changes (or make another temp branch and merge), then check out the other branch, and then apply that stash and handle the conflict.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I indeed got confused between working folder and branch. Your explanation helped me solve this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to use stash of master branch at another branch. Did you `git stash branch branchName`? With this you can create new branch and pop the changes to the new branch. But make sure you save the code before this command.

Comment: Yes, that's right. This will pop the changes of master into the current branch. How can I revert master without losing the uncommitted changes on the new branch?

Comment: By committing them with new branch and then reset the master? Or you can get patch of the code and apply it after reset (if don't want to commit the new branch) https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/create-and-apply-patch/

Comment: If you have not changed master **then you don't need to reset master**. All this talk about the reset command just tells me that there's going to be lost changes in the near future. **You do not need to use the reset command**

Answer (score 0):

If your changes are stages (you have run `git add`), then you need first to unstage those changes with `git reset --mixed`.

Now you have unstaged changes, which are not tracked by git, so you can freely change branch to the other one and there you can add those changes and carry on with your work.